# Issue using ControlClick and WinTitle

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to the AHK and trying to make a script to click on a coordinate in a specific window, once per minute.

I already used the WindowSpy to get the coordinates and the WindowTitle, but i can't get to work

Right now the script is:

`ControlClick, x469 y363, ahk_pid 11532`

Am i missing something?? Thanks!

edit1: I changed the script to this and tested in another window like Excel and it worked, but in the game that it is supposed to work, it doesnt, no idea why

```
ControlClick, x466 y364, ahk_pid 11532,,,, Pos
sleep 60000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just pasted in that code badly, or it really looks like that, but a simple loop can be used to achieve that. (Possibly not the most ideal thing to use, depends on if you want the script to do something else as well)

```
Loop
{
    ControlClick, x466 y364, ahk_pid 11532,,,, Pos NA
    Sleep, 60000
}
```

Also I recommend at least trying out the [`NA`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm#Parameters) option, it's documented as possibly improving reliability.

And about it not working in some game you're trying, it's very much expected. More often than not games will receive input in some way which makes control clicking not work. For example receiving direct input.

There's not much you can do about that, and it can get really complicated/advanced.
Again, I don't know what what sort of game you're talking about, but going into windowed mode (assuming fullscreen even is a thing for the game) and actually moving the cursor and then clicking might work. But that of course defeats the purpose of even using ControlClick in the first place..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the loop part didnt paste correctly. I tried with NA too, but probably the game is not compatible. I will have to continue to use the "normal click" function with the window active

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @0x464e is good if you're only running one process within the script. If want to run multiple processes use the [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) function.

```
SetTimer, ClickOneMin, 60000
return

ClickOneMin:
ControlClick, x466 y364, ahk_pid 11532,,,, Pos NA
return
```

This will allow you to add additional loops, timers and processes.